# Inferschema detecting column as string instead of double from parquet in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

Problem -
I am reading a parquet file in pyspark using azure databricks. There are columns which lot of nulls and have decimal values, these columns are read as string instead of double.

Is there any way of inferring the proper data type in pyspark?

Code -

To read parquet file -

```
df_raw_data = sqlContext.read.parquet(data_filename[5:])
```

The output of this is a dataframe with more than 100 columns of which most of the columns are of the type double but the printSchema() shows it as string.

P.S -
I have a parquet file which can have dynamic columns hence defining struct for the dataframe does not work for me. I used to convert the spark dataframe to pandas and use convert_objects but that does not work as the parquet file is huge.

Comment: pls show your code

Comment: Hi @thebluephantom I have added the code in the function.

Comment: why are you using `format("com.github.saurfang.sas.spark")`? It's not a parquet... I think that you may need to look to `inferDecimal` and other options of that format

Comment: @AlexOtt sorry pasted the sas file load, have updated the parquet file load now.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the schema using StructType and then provide this schema in the schema option while loading the data.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, DoubleType
fileSchema = StructType([StructField('atm_id', StringType(),True),
                        StructField('atm_street_number', IntegerType(),True),
                        StructField('atm_zipcode', IntegerType(),True),
                        StructField('atm_lat', DoubleType(),True),
                        ])
df_raw_data = spark.read \
.option("header",True) \
.option("format", "parquet") \
.schema(fileSchema) \
.load(data_filename[5:])
```